# JS Jest: getting undefined error on simple mock test

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I have a simple function that takes a `player` and calls a nested function `setPlayer()` on it:

```
myFunction = (player) => {
    player.getData().setPlayer(true)
}
```

**main.test.js**

```
it('expects setPlayer to be called', () => {

    player = jest.fn();

    // mocking the myFunction 

    player.getData = jest.fn(() => {
      return {
        setPlayer: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true),
      }
    })

    myFunction(player) // calling function

    expects(player.getData.setPlayer).toBeCalled();
});
```

I keep getting this error in my test though but I don't understand why.  I seem to have everything mocked unless I am forgetting something:

```
expect(received).toBeCalled()

Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

Received has value: undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I keep getting this error in my test though but I don't understand why.

`player.getData` is a mock function. That function doesn't have a `setPlayer` property. You are passing `undefined` to `expects`, hence the error.

**Calling** `player.getData` would return you an object with a `setPlayer` function, but you can't just do `expects(player.getData().setPlayer)` because that would return a *different* `setPlayer` mock function than the one called by `myFunction`.

Instead you simply create the `setPlayer` mock function up front and reference it directly. I also cleaned up the code a little.

```
it('expects setPlayer to be called', () => {

    const setPlayerMock = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true);
    const player = {
      getData: jest.fn(() => {
        return {
          setPlayer: setPlayerMock,
        };
      }),
    };

    myFunction(player); // calling function

    expects(setPlayerMock).toBeCalled();
});
```

---

FWIW, with the information you have given, it wouldn't be necessary to use a mock function for `getData`, you could just do

```
const player = {
  getData() {
    return {setPlayer: setPlayerMock};
  },
}
```

You only need to use mock functions when you want to make assertions on them.

Comment: thanks Felix, I appreciate the explanation.  Would you happen to know of any resources for jest?  The docs are good but seeing examples and explanations would be useful too.